# Sass function with import

Tags: function, import, sass

I have a simple function in Sass that don't work. I try to import an url by a slug. This is because I have a complex path and don't want to repeat myself.

```
@function import($name){
    @return $name + '/' + $name + '.scss';
}

@import import('reset');
```

The function above is simplified but have everything that is needed.

**Error message**

> @import directive requires a url or quoted path

I've tried to att quotes but it did not go well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great implementation, but still is a WIP, you can check **[the issue master ref](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1094)** to track the progress